# PHP/Ajax auto refresh script - Add multiple fields

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Sorry for my english. I try to modify this script which uses AJAX to look for changes in a database table, and if a change is detected, return information from that table : http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii/

Problem is I need more than one field in the form (add.php). You'll find below all original files.
I tried to modify add.php according to my needs but I don't know how to play with strip_tags. I'm beginner and lost with syntax.
This is what I did with add.php :

```
<?php require('common.php');
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title2']) && !empty($_POST['title3']) ){
    $result = $db->add_news(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
}?>
```

db.php :

```
function add_news($title){
        $title = $this->db->real_escape_string($title);
        if($this->db->query('INSERT into news (title) VALUES ("'.$title.' '.$title2.' '.$title3.'")')){
            $this->register_changes();
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Aditional fields are blank but it's not a surprise as I think i'm missing things. I need some help, thank you.

Original files, add.php :

```
<?php require('common.php');
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['title'])){
    $result = $db->add_news(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
}?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add news - Demo for Ajax Autorefresh</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a demo for post <a href="http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii">Ajax Auto Refresh - Volume II</a></h1>
    <p>Open <a href="index.php">list of messages</a> in new window, add new message with this form and look at that list. Don't refresh it manually. It should refresh automatically after 20 seconds.<p>
    <?php if(isset($result)){
        if($result==TRUE){
            echo '<p>Success</p>';
        }else{
            echo '<p>Error</p>';
        }
    }else{?>
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="title" size="50" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add message" />
        </form>
    <?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

common.php :

```
<?php
require_once ('db.php'); //get our database class
$db = new db();
/* end of file common.php */
```

db.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * Class db for Ajax Auto Refresh - Volume II - demo
 *
 * @author Eliza Witkowska <kokers@codebusters.pl>
 * @link http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii
 */
class db{

    /**
     * db
     *
     * @var $   public $db;
     */
    public $db;


    /**
     * __construct
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function __construct(){
        $this->db_connect('localhost','test','xxxxx','test');
    }


    /**
     * db_connect
     *
     * Connect with database
     *
     * @param mixed $host
     * @param mixed $user
     * @param mixed $pass
     * @param mixed $database
     * @return void
     */
    function db_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database){
        $this->db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

        if($this->db->connect_errno > 0){
            die('Unable to connect to database [' . $this->db->connect_error . ']');
        }
    }


    /**
     * check_changes
     *
     * Get counter value from database
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function check_changes(){
        $result = $this->db->query('SELECT counting FROM news WHERE id=1');
        if($result = $result->fetch_object()){
            return $result->counting;
        }
        return 0;
    }


    /**
     * register_changes
     *
     * Increase value of counter in database. Should be called everytime when
     * something change (add,edit or delete)
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function register_changes(){
        $this->db->query('UPDATE news SET counting = counting + 1 WHERE id=1');
    }


    /**
     * get_news
     *
     * Get list of news
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function get_news(){
        if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id<>1 ORDER BY add_date DESC LIMIT 50')){
            $return = '';
            while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
                $return .= '<p>id: '.$r->id.' | '.htmlspecialchars($r->title).'</p>';
                $return .= '<hr/>';
            }
            return $return;
        }
    }


    /**
     * add_news
     *
     * Add new message
     *
     * @param mixed $title
     * @return void
     */
    function add_news($title){
        $title = $this->db->real_escape_string($title);
        if($this->db->query('INSERT into news (title) VALUES ("'.$title.'")')){
            $this->register_changes();
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
/* End of file db.php */
```

Comment: _"I don't know how to play with strip_tags"_ - [Have you check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

Comment: Not really sure what your real issue is. Just add a new element to the form, update the call to pass the new field as a second argument and update the method `add_news()` to receive and store the second argument as well.